# systemd service unit fails on startup

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, systemd, powertop

I wanted to change certain powertop params on Ubuntu 17.04 startup, therefore I created a shell script in `/usr/sbin/` and made it executable:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo 'min_power' > '/sys/class/scsi_host/host1/link_power_management_policy';
echo 'min_power' > '/sys/class/scsi_host/host2/link_power_management_policy';
echo 'min_power' > '/sys/class/scsi_host/host0/link_power_management_policy';
echo 'min_power' > '/sys/class/scsi_host/host5/link_power_management_policy';
echo 'min_power' > '/sys/class/scsi_host/host3/link_power_management_policy';
echo 'min_power' > '/sys/class/scsi_host/host4/link_power_management_policy';
echo '1' > '/sys/module/snd_hda_intel/parameters/power_save';
echo 'auto' > '/sys/bus/i2c/devices/i2c-0/device/power/control';
echo 'auto' > '/sys/bus/i2c/devices/i2c-1/device/power/control';
echo 'auto' > '/sys/bus/i2c/devices/i2c-2/device/power/control';
echo 'auto' > '/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:1d.0/power/control';
echo 'auto' > '/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:1f.3/power/control';
echo 'auto' > '/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:00.0/power/control';
echo 'auto' > '/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:1f.6/power/control';
echo 'auto' > '/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:02.0/power/control';
echo 'auto' > '/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:14.0/power/control';
echo 'auto' > '/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:1f.4/power/control';
echo 'auto' > '/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:17.0/power/control';
echo 'auto' > '/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:1f.2/power/control';
echo 'auto' > '/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:1c.0/power/control';
echo 'auto' > '/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:1f.0/power/control';
echo 'auto' > '/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:16.0/power/control';
ethtool -s  enp0s31f6 wol d
exit 0
```

Then I made a service unit in `/etc/systemd/system` :

```
[Unit]
Description=PowerTOP

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/powertop-stup.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

and enabled it with `sudo systemctl enable powertop_start.service`
but after a reboot it does not work.

If I start the service manually after booting with `sudo systemctl start powertop_start.service` it works flawlessly. Also when I start the shell script itself it works but automatically on boot it does nothing.

Comment: And what does `journalctl -u powertop_start.service` say after it fails to start as expected on boot? Does `systemctl status powertop_start` show anything interesting?

Comment: systemctl status powertop_start gives me `powertop_start.service - PowerTOP
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/powertop_start.service; enabled; vendor
   Active: inactive (dead) since Thu 2017-05-11 21:10:07 CEST; 53s ago
 Main PID: 787 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

May 11 21:10:06 mediaserver systemd[1]: Started PowerTOP.`  and journalctl -u powertop_start.service gives me `Logs begin at Thu 2017-05-11 21:10:05 CEST, end at Thu 2017-05-11 21:17:01 CE
May 11 21:10:06 mediaserver systemd[1]: Started PowerTOP.
`

Comment: But are the logs only from the the attempted startup, or did you capture the logs only after your successful manual run of the service?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why your service doesn't work, but I believe the standard way to make changes to `/sys` at boot is to use `sysfsutils`, so I'm suggesting that as an alternative approach.

The package may not be installed by default, so first do:

```
sudo apt install sysfsutils
```

now edit the file `/etc/sysfs.conf`, for example:

```
sudoedit /etc/sysfs.conf
```

and add these lines to the end of it

```
class/scsi_host/host1/link_power_management_policy = min_power
class/scsi_host/host2/link_power_management_policy = min_power
class/scsi_host/host0/link_power_management_policy = min_power
class/scsi_host/host5/link_power_management_policy = min_power
class/scsi_host/host3/link_power_management_policy = min_power 
class/scsi_host/host4/link_power_management_policy = min_power
module/snd_hda_intel/parameters/power_save = 1
bus/i2c/devices/i2c-0/device/power/control = auto
bus/i2c/devices/i2c-1/device/power/control = auto
bus/i2c/devices/i2c-2/device/power/control = auto
bus/pci/devices/0000:00:1d.0/power/control = auto
bus/pci/devices/0000:00:1f.3/power/control = auto
bus/pci/devices/0000:00:00.0/power/control = auto
bus/pci/devices/0000:00:1f.6/power/control = auto
bus/pci/devices/0000:00:02.0/power/control = auto
bus/pci/devices/0000:00:14.0/power/control = auto
bus/pci/devices/0000:00:1f.4/power/control = auto
bus/pci/devices/0000:00:17.0/power/control = auto
bus/pci/devices/0000:00:1f.2/power/control = auto
bus/pci/devices/0000:00:1c.0/power/control = auto
bus/pci/devices/0000:00:1f.0/power/control = auto
bus/pci/devices/0000:00:16.0/power/control = auto
```

Save the file and exit, and reboot.

That leaves your `ethtool` command, which I don't have a solution for, but you might see if systemd will run only that command for you as detailed [in this answer by muru](https://askubuntu.com/questions/814/how-to-run-scripts-on-start-up/719157#719157).